# Correct way of Implementation of equals() method for JPA entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have used Eclipse to generate `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods for my JPA entities by selecting fields/attributes of interest.

However, I have observed that Eclipse seems to add below lines in generated `equals` method:

```
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
```

It seems logical to have the above check, but I am using LAZY loaded relations in all my JPA entities, and I have observed that in certain instances above check fails when `obj`'s class is some kind of proxied class and the main object is of the Entity in question - I have inspected the class of objects being compared and both are not exactly same, and hence the above condition evaluates to `false` even though the objects represented same record from database.

Hence, my query is should we compare class of objects when we implement `equals()` method for JPA entities.

Comment: Typically, that check is there to prevent a `ClassCastException`. Do the proxy class and main entity class both have a common parent for you to cast to?

Comment: I try to compare an instance of `Student` class with collection of `Student` class instances - with first instance being read from DB, whereas collection is lazily initialized as it is part of child relationship to another Entity, say `College`

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Can your code run without the `if` statement there? If so, you can be more lenient and use an `instanceof` check instead of comparing `getClass()`.

Comment: I will have to check on that - meanwhile, shouldn't this issue be faced by others also as I am not sure I am doing anything out of ordinary by working with lazily loaded instances?

Comment: I think you can only rely on `instanceof` if  there is proxies involved and you want a generic `Object.equals` method. For entities of the same class/type the Eclipse way must work

Comment: I'm not experienced in using lazily loaded instances, but if you want to use `equals()` between two objects, you are free to customize it however you like as long as you abide by the [specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended to use **business key equality** for JPA entities.
Autogenerated equals uses all fields.

Most likely your entity has technical, autogenerated primary key (id field). That field is populated by database, after entity is persisted. 
If you have autogenerated equals/hashcode, it includes all class fields- including that id field.
Therefore equals/hashcode for your entity will change after you persist it, without changing any other field (before persist id will be null, after persist not null).

For more details read
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/persistent-classes-equalshashcode.html

this is Hibernate reference, but all concepts related to primary key should apply to any JPA provider.

Comment: Absolutely agree with @Bartosz Bilicki, because JPA entity it's only java view for database row. According to sql documentation `The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table`. So, if you have two entities with same ID, it mean that it is same entity.

Comment: I do not use all fields/attributes of class - in Eclipse, when you use option `Source -> Generated equals and hashcode`, it provides a GUI to select fields that will establish natural equality.