# Two ways to identify the same entity for easier testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, testing

I have a class, for example

```
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Entity
public class MovieBoxOfficeEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private Long id;
}
```

which has an ID generated automatically without being manually set. I also have a class with a method

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "movies")
public class MovieEntity {

       List<MovieBoxOffice> boxOffices = new ArrayList<>();

       public void addBoxOffice(MovieBoxOffice boxOffice) throws ResourceConflictException {
            if (this.boxOffices.contains(boxOffice)) {
                 throw new ResourceConflictException("A box office with id " + boxOffice.getId() + " is already added");
            }
           this.boxOffices.add(boxOffice);
      }
}
```

There is a problem with testing the method `addBoxOffice`, because the comparison of `MovieBoxOfficeEntity` objects is done using the `ID`, and the `ID` is only generated automatically when writing to the database and can not be set manually.

I came up with the idea of adding the `uniqueId` field to the `MovieBoxOfficeEntity` class and adding it to the `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation

```
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "uniqueId"})
@Entity
public class MovieBoxOfficeEntity {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
        private Long id;

        private String uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

then I can test this way

```
@Test(expected = ResourceConflictException.class)
public void canAddBoxOffice() throws ResourceConflictException{
    final String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    final MovieBoxOfficeEntity boxOffice = new MovieBoxOfficeEntity();
    boxOffice.setUniqueId(id);

    this.movieEntity.addBoxOffice(boxOffice);
    this.movieEntity.addBoxOffice(boxOffice);
}
```

in this way, the object `boxOffice` will have

```
id: null
uniqueId: some generated UUID
```

and the comparison of objects will take place on the `uniqueId` comparison.

What do you think about creating a `uniqueId` field just to test the entity methods?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way of Implementation of equals() method for JPA entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394399/correct-way-of-implementation-of-equals-method-for-jpa-entities)

Answer (score 0):

Adding **uniqueId** can lead to collisions. Suppose there are two finders. When their result is created, two instances will be created for the same rows in the database. They will have the same **id**, but different **uniqueId**. Means, two objects have the same primary key, but **equals** return **false**. This can lead to errors in the application logic and in the JPA implementation.

You can override **equals**. But use the entity attributes that are related to your table, not the randomly generated UUIDs.

Comment: So, do you think to use all fields (attributes) from an object to enumerate hashCode?

Comment: @ewsgfsdgdfgh: All fields (attributes) or not, it depends on your business logic. Suppose entity has attributes id, firstName, lastName, birthDate, birthPlace. Then yes, if you exclude some attributes from comparison (birthDate, birthPlace), two different persons will be considered as equal. Suppose you have one more attribute, lastLoginDate (we don't talk that this may be not good DB design :) ). In some cases lastLoginDate can be not important for comparison of two person entities, on others, if this represents login record, it may be important.